# How to determine number of hops using a vector?

Tags: matlab

[image]

I have a MATLAB matrix like below:

```
column no:        1 2 3 4 5 6
matrix elements   1 1 2 3 6 2
```

Column numbers represent node ID and elements of the matrix represent the node towards which that node points. Please help me find hop count from a particular node to node 1. I have written the following code but it doesn't solve the problem.

```
x = ones(1, n);
checkbit = zeros(1, n);
nodedest = [1 1 2 3 6 2];
hopcount = zeros(1, n);

for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        if nodedest(j) == 1 && checkbit(j) == 0
            hopcount(j) = hopcount(j) + 1;
            checkbit(j) = 1;
        else
            x(j) = nodedest(j);
        end
        if x(j) ~= 1
            hopcount(j) = hopcount(j) + 1;
            x(j) = nodedest(x(j));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you give an example worked out by hand?

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks for replying. I have updated my post, please check it.

Comment: You are looking for breath-first search

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [breadth-first search](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) to find the [shortest path](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem) in your graph. Without touching the data in any way, you can do this in O(n) time per node, given the tree-like structure of your graph:

```
nodedest = [1 1 2 3 6 2];
hopcount = zeros(1, 6);
for n = 2:6
    k = n
    while k ~= 1
        hopcount(n) = hopcount(n) + 1
        k = nodedest(k)
    end
end
```

If you are willing to reverse the sense of your edges (introducing a one-to-many relationship), you could accomplish the same thing in one pass, reducing the entire algorithm from O(n<sup>2</sup>) to O(n) time complexity. The trade-off would be that memory complexity would increase from O(1) to O(n):

```
nodedest = [1 1 2 3 6 2];

% Reverse the input
nodesource = cell(1, 6);
nodesource(:) = {[]}
for n = 2:6
    k = nodedest(n);
    nodesource{k} = [nodesource{k} n];
end

% implement bfs, using the assumption that the graph is a simple tree
hopcount = zeros(1, 6);
cache = [1];
hops = 0;
while ~isempty(cache)
    next = []
    for c = cache
        hopcount(c) = hops;
        next = [next nodesource(c)]
    end
    hops = hops + 1;
    cache = next
end
```